# Putting border around header

Tags: html, css, header, border

I'm trying to put a border around a header, nothing seems to be working... apologies, I'm pretty new to all of this, so is there another way?

```css
header {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 852px;
  height: 179px;
  border: 10px #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Vincent_van_Gogh_-_Self-portrait_with_grey_felt_hat_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg/250px-Vincent_van_Gogh_-_Self-portrait_with_grey_felt_hat_-_Google_Art_Project.jpg");
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://www.brandbucket.com/sites/default/files/logo_uploads/284255/large_titletext.png" alt="ninenonzeg">
</header>
```

Comment: You need to tell what [type of border](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border) and it has to have a visible colour. Try `border: 10px solid #000;`

Answer (score -1):

Change the border color then try to do that. I think that your background color and border color are similar.  And also give the style of the border.

```
border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
```

or

```
border-style:solid;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Add `solid` attribute to border in css.
do

```
  border: 10px solid #FFFFFF;
```

make sure you need a #FFF (white) border